Model failed to converge using glmer
My dependent variable is actigtraph measurements measured every minute for 55 individuals (count data- right skewed, most values at 0). I have around 1.2m rows. Here is my simple random intercept model:
model1 <- glmer.nb(activity ~ rescale_minute + (1|individual), data = data, 
           glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5, 
                        maxIter = 1000)))


This is the error that I encounter:
 Error in f_refitNB(lastfit, theta = exp(t), control = control) : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in  
   pwrssUpdate
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.794566 (tol = 0.002, 
        component 1)

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Welcome to CV. For a question like this it would be good to specify in the title that it's a neg in model with millions of observations.  Define actigtraph in the question also .  As for the reason, here are some trouble shooting tips, in case you haven't tried them.  1) try a poison model. 2) run a non mixed effects version 3) subset the data to a much small size (eg 10 k rows  or less)
